# Grouping rows with same value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in excel and I want to create a Macro in VBA to **group rows with the same Value** in Column F and highlight the title group in bold.

In other words, All the rows with the same value in Column F, must be group in one row with the tittle in bold. Its possible?

This is what I have:
[Actual Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADXx7.png)

```
    Dim r As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
        ' expand all groups on sheet
        .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
        ' remove any existing groups
        .Rows.Ungroup
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set r = .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))
        r.Select
    End With

    With r
        j = 1
        v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                ' Colum B changed, create group
                v = .Cells(i, 1)
                If i > j + 1 Then
                    .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
                End If
                j = i
                v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' create last group
        If i > j + 1 Then
            .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
        End If
        ' collapse all groups
        .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    End With
```

This is what I want:

[image: Expected Data]

Thanks so much, I'll be very greatful

Comment: @Javi - Even if this site was a "free coding service", grouping rows with the same value doesn't require VBA, and is accomplished with a few clicks by creating a **PivotTable**.

Comment: See MS Office Support: [**Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data**](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) and also [**Group or ungroup data in a PivotTable**](https://support.office.com/article/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725).

Comment: @Ashleedawg I want to group with the plus icon, so Pivot table doesnt work for me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Javi do you mean [group like this?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff)

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious yes, its correct!! :)

Comment: Ok, I've got a handle on your code.  You're missing the bold and the highlight. Is that all you need or is there something that it's not doing properly?

Comment: I think is all I need. I dont know if how I did it its the best solution.

Comment: Take a look at this [output](https://imgur.com/a/tFBAB2f) is that what you're looking for?  I think maybe you only wanted one row formatted.... that's what I'd want but I was having fun and got carried away.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious the output is empty :(

Comment: I've no clue what you mean by that.  I start with a spreadsheet.that doesn't have a group or highlighting.  There are repeat values in column F.  I run the code and the sheet is grouped by column F, all  rows in that group are formatted, and the group is collapsed.  The output shows the group expanded and collapsed.  Further, the grouping is done by your code with no changes to the grouping functionality.  I only added formatting.

Comment: I refer to your link is empty https://imgur.com/a/tFBAB2f :) but now appears! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it more visually appealing to highlight just the top most row but you requested all rows so this will explain how to do it both ways.  I am 100% certain this is highly inefficient but it provides minimal alteration to your existing code and provides the result you wanted.

For both versions, you'll need one more range variable.  Technically it isn't needed but I didn't feel like doing mental gymnastics with i and j

```
Dim rng As Range
```

And almost at the very bottom, insert a conditional test and formatting.

```
' create last group
If i > j + 1 Then
    .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        rng.Interior.Color = 65535
        rng.Font.Bold = True
        Set rng = Nothing
    End If
End If
```

To format only the topmost row in the group, add an `else` and formatting - DO NOT USE THIS SEGMENT IF YOU WANT TO HIGHLIGHT ALL ROWS

```
If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
    ' Colum B changed, create group
    v = .Cells(i, 1)
    If i > j + 1 Then
        .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
    End If
    j = i
    v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
Else
    Set rng = .Cells(j, 1)
    rng.EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535
    rng.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
End If
```

To format every row in the group, declare one more iterative variable and use this segment instead

```
Dim k as long
If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
    ' Colum B changed, create group
    v = .Cells(i, 1)
    If i > j + 1 Then
        .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For k = 0 To 1
                rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + k, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
                rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + k, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535
                rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + k, 1).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
            Next
            Set rng = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    j = i
    v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
Else
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    Else
        Set rng = .Cells(j, 1)
    End If
End If
```

One of those two variants should get you where you want to go.

Comment: Highlights only the top most row its fine for me! :)

Thank you so much @ProfoundlyOblivious